# Proper way to load assets with a FSM transition between menus and actual game

Tags: c++, sdl, fsm

So far I am making a game in C++ and SDL, and the way to switch between the different menus and the actual game is via a Finite State Machine, AKA a stack where I put each state (MenuState, GameState...) on top, and only render and update the top of said stack.

Now I need to load assets such as images, and I am thinking of creating a class for each state which will hold all the address of the textures, sound, etc and pass it to each state so that it can render, play sound, etc, properly.

Something like a GameAsset class that I pass to `GameState(GameAsset ga)` when I create one, so that `GameState::render()` can do its work fast.

Is there any better way (easier to implement, faster, whatever) to do this ? It seem like it's stretched out for me, as I haven't made games on this scale before. Will this become unmaintainable or whatever ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consideration: as retrieving the `GameAssets` inside `GameState::render` will be done only once per frame, there's no consideration of efficiency to be had -- no sensible solution will have any impact.

That aside, let's consider our options. `GameState::render` is a member function, so there are three ways it can retrieve an object:

### Global variable

The usual one. You'd have a global `GameAssets *gGameAssets;`, that is assigned to the `GameAssets` instance once constructed. This is technically the simplest solution, but global variables are usually frown upon because maintenance is an issue: that simplicity means that absolutely no dependency is visible from the outside, so you don't know that `GameState::render` needs and uses `gGameAssets`. Moving on.

### Member variable

`GameState` would hold a `GameAssets *` as a member variable. The pattern you've shown, providing the `GameState` with its `GameAssets` upon construction, is known as Dependency Injection. It's pretty good maintenance-wise: the caller governs which `GameAssets` goes to which `GameState`, and the dependency is visible.

### Function parameter

This one is not always practical, but it should be in this case. There's a good chance that `GameState::render` is the only function from `GameState` that needs the `GameAssets`, and that the function calling `GameState::render` also has access to the `GameAssets`. How about just passing a parameter, i.e. `GameState::render(GameAssets &assets)`? Now the dependency is both explicit *and* tightly localized to the `render` call.

### The choice

It's simple: from bottom to top, pick the first practical solution :)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I'm going to do a mix of 2 and 3, when it's practical. A global variable just doesn't feel right :)

Comment: Particularly, in case where a single object is using assets, it make sense to store it in that object. But if it's a tons of them, it's best to send them the parameters, as those objects have to be stored, and any more data stored in them will increase the memory usage too much.